# Serial read write with Baud rate 9600 , parity none, data bits 8 and stop bits 2. Unable to communicate with device

Tags: c, posix, embedded-linux, termios

I am working on project which requires to send command in hex with device setting as follows : 
Baud rate : 9600, Parity : None, Stop bits : 2 , data bits : 8 (9600, 8N2).

I have verified by sending data to device with minicom. I am able to see data on CRO. But when I am sending data via C code and unable to see data on CRO and getting program output as FFFFF always for read function.

Source code for serial read and write :

```
int32_t Read()
{
   printf("Entering Read function \n");
   int fd;
   fd = open("/dev/ttyS1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
   int j=0;

    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS1\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Port /dev/ttyS1 opened successfully\n"); 
    }

    //---------- Setting the Attributes of the serial port using termios structure --------- 

        struct termios SerialPortSettings;  // Create the structure                          

        tcgetattr(fd, &SerialPortSettings); // Get the current attributes of the Serial port 

        cfsetispeed(&SerialPortSettings,B9600); // Set Read  Speed as 9600                       
        cfsetospeed(&SerialPortSettings,B9600); // Set Write Speed as 9600                       

        SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;   // Disables the Parity Enable bit(PARENB),So No Parity 
        SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~PARODD; // added

        SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |=  CS8;      // Set the data bits = 8    
        SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= CSTOPB;   // CSTOPB = 2 Stop bits
        SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;    // Clears the mask for setting the data size            


        SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;       // No Hardware flow Control                         
        SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |= (CREAD | CLOCAL); // Enable receiver,Ignore Modem Control lines       

        SerialPortSettings.c_lflag =0; /* RAW input */ // added

        SerialPortSettings.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);          // Disable XON/XOFF flow control both i/p and o/p 
        SerialPortSettings.c_iflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);  // Non Cannonical mode   

        SerialPortSettings.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0; // added for testing // added 1 sec
        SerialPortSettings.c_cc[VTIME] = 5; // added for testing // added

        SerialPortSettings.c_iflag = 0;            /* SW flow control off, no parity checks etc */ // added

        SerialPortSettings.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;// No Output Processing

        if((tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&SerialPortSettings)) != 0) // Set the attributes to the termios structure
            printf("\n  ERROR ! in Setting attributes");
        else
                    printf("\n  BaudRate = 9600 \n  StopBits = 2 \n  Parity   = None\n");

     //------------------------------- Write data to serial port -----------------------------

        unsigned char write_buffer[] = {0x28,0x11,0xDF,0xBC};   // Buffer containing characters to write into port       

        int  bytes_written  = 0;    // Value for storing the number of bytes written to the port 

        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            bytes_written = write(fd,write_buffer[j],sizeof(write_buffer));// use write() to send data to port                                           
                                             // "fd"                   - file descriptor pointing to the opened serial port 
                                            //  "write_buffer"         - address of the buffer containing data              
                                             // "sizeof(write_buffer)" - No of bytes to write  
                                             //
            printf("Byte written : %x\n",write_buffer[j]);                                   
            printf("\n  %d Bytes written to ttyS1", bytes_written);
            printf("\n +----------------------------------+\n\n");

        }

        sleep(2);   

        //------------------------------- Read data from serial port -----------------------------

        tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);  //  Discards old data in the rx buffer            

        unsigned char read_buffer[40];  //  Buffer to store the data received              
        int  bytes_read = 0;   //  Number of bytes read by the read() system call 
        int i = 0;


        bytes_read = read(fd,&read_buffer,40); // Read the data                  

        printf("\n\n  Bytes Rxed -%x", bytes_read); // Print the number of bytes read 
        printf("\n\n  ");

        for(i=0;i<bytes_read;i++)    //printing only the received characters
            printf("%x",(int)(*(unsigned char*)(&read_buffer[i])));

        printf("\n +----------------------------------+\n\n\n");

        close(fd); // Close the serial port 



  printf("Exiting Read function \n");   
}
```

Output :

```
Entering Read function 

Port /dev/ttyS1 opened successfully

  BaudRate = 9600 
  StopBits = 2 
  Parity   = None
Byte written : 28

  -1 Bytes written to ttyS1
 +----------------------------------+

Byte written : 11

  -1 Bytes written to ttyS1
 +----------------------------------+

Byte written : df

  -1 Bytes written to ttyS1
 +----------------------------------+

Byte written : bc

  -1 Bytes written to ttyS1
 +----------------------------------+

  Bytes Rxed -ffffffff

 +----------------------------------+
Exiting Read function
```

Comment: Could you tell us what devices are involved? Is this between a μC and a PC?  If so what kind of micro?  What lines are connected?  Just TX and RX?

Comment: I am using openwrt build. Ponsel optod sensor is connected to board and I am accessing via serial port ttyS1.

Comment: So it's an embedded (networking?) device using openwrt, and you're trying to talk to an oxygen sensor over UART at 9600 8N2, am I correct so far?

Comment: Yes . Correct. I am trying exactly same thing.

Comment: I can see you're writing to your device with `write()`.  But I can also see you're using Canonical mode.  According to [this page I found](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man5/struct_termios.5.asp), commands are terminated either with `\n` or `EOF`.  But you're not sending either of these.  Try adding an `\n` to the end of your write buffer.

Comment: I tried sending string as {0x28,0x11,0xDF,0xBC,0x0D,0x0A} also  checked with  {0x28,0x11,0xDF,0xBC,0x0A} but result was same.

Comment: Also tried to print termios attributes . I am getting result as zero for speed. Pls suggest.                                                                              printf("Current i/p Baudrate : %u \n", cfgetispeed(&SerialPortSettings));
        printf("Current o/p Baudrate : %u \n", cfgetospeed(&SerialPortSettings));

Comment: In case you haven't noticed, all of your serial terminal I/O by your program is unsuccessful.  For every **write()** and **read()** syscall you are getting back a -1 for the return code, but your program fails to report the ***errno*** which would provide details on the failure.  *"getting program output as FFFFF always for read function"* -- What are you calling *"program output"*?  The read error is probably due to your use of non-blocking mode, but the ***errno*** from the **write()** should be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st of all add error checking to this call:

```
  tcgetattr(fd, &SerialPortSettings);
```

like

```
if (0 > tcgetattr(fd, &SerialPortSettings))
{
  /* log and handle error */ 
}
```

Then here

```
  SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |=  CS8;
```

you set the data bits.

Two lines below you clear it

```
  SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
```

Do this the other way round.

Also this

```
  SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= CSTOPB;
```

unsets.

If you want to use 2 stop bits *set* it by doing

```
  SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |= CSTOPB;
```

---

Instead of just doing

```
  SerialPortSettings.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
```

do

```
  SerialPortSettings.c_oflag = 0;
```

---

The code calls `write()` wrongly. This

```
   for(j=0;j<4;j++)
   {
     bytes_written = write(fd,write_buffer[j],sizeof(write_buffer));
```

ought to be

```
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
      bytes_written = write(fd, &write_buffer[j], 1)
```

Or just drop the loop and do

```
    bytes_written = write(fd, write_buffer, sizeof write_buffer);
```

The call to `read()` is wrong as well.

It should be

```
    bytes_read = read(fd, read_buffer, ...
```

For some of those mistakes with `write` and `read` the compiler should have warned you about.

Please also note that `read()` and `write()` return `ssize_t` not `int`.

---

Last not least I doubt flushing the input buffer (`tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);`) before reading it makes sense.

Comment: I have changed setting as per your suggestion. Result is same.  Could you pls suggest for speed also?                                                  getspeed results I am geting as                                                           Current i/p Baudrate : 13   
Current o/p Baudrate : 13

Comment: Changed  to SerialPortSettings.c_oflag = 0; write  buffer is {0x28,0x11,0xDF,0xBC,0x0A}. Still I am unable to see buffer in CRO. Pls suggest.

Comment: Thanks for identifying these mistakes. I'll definitely take care warnings in future also. Now for speed I am getting result as 13. Also final output of read is same as fffff.

Comment: @AmrutaSant: `B9600` is a `#define` which most likely equals `13`. To double check print `B9600` as well.

Comment: Beware that the "further readings" link has low-quality code that is not POSIX compliant, and may not work in every situation.  The use of non-blocking mode is problematic.  See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237)
and [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html)  Even one of the suggestions in this answer (i.e. `SerialPortSettings.c_oflag = 0;` ) is dubious.